# How to pass selected dropdown value using javascript to Html.ActionLink

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a LocationCode dropdown:

```
@Html.DropDownList("LocationCode", (SelectList)ViewBag.Values, "Search Location...", new { @value = "@ViewBag.LocationCode.ToString()", @class = "form-control btn btn-default dropdown-toggle", name = "LocationCode" })
```

Below is my `@Html.ActionLink` which calls an Export to Excel function:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Export to Excel", "ExportAllVehicleLocationsToExcel", new { id = "ExportAllVehicleLocationsToExcel" })
```

Here is my Javascript attempt which is not working:

```
jQuery(function () {
    $("#ExportAllVehicleLocationsToExcel").click(
    function AllVehicleLocationsSearch() {
        $('#LocationCode').val(LocationCode);
        }
    );
});
```

How do I pass the selected LocationCode to the `@Html.ActionLink` using Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build a new url based on the selected value

The code for generating the  should be just (never set the `value` attribute when using the `HtmlHelper` methods, and your attempt at setting the `name` attribute fortunately does nothing at all)

```
@Html.DropDownList("LocationCode", (SelectList)ViewBag.Values, "Search Location...",
    new { @class = "form-control btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" })
```

and the link can be just

```
<a href="#" id="export">Export to Excel</a>
```

and then the script will be

```
var baseUrl = '@Url.Action("ExportAllVehicleLocationsToExcel")';
$('#export').click(function() {
    location.href = baseUrl + '/' + $('#LocationCode').val();
})
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen but am I missing something here? The URL rendered locally is just http://localhost:56694/# Do I need to change this? `<a href="#"`

Comment: No. Its the `var baseUrl = '@Url.Action("ExportAllVehicleLocationsToExcel")';` that is generating the url.

Comment: And if the value of the option is say 12, clicking on the link will execute the script and generate `.../yourController/ExportAllVehicleLocationsToExcel/12` and redirect to the `ExportAllVehicleLocationsToExcel` method

Comment: it's not working locally. It renders as # no matter what is selected. Maybe my syntax is wrong?  `<script>
 var baseUrl = '@Url.Action("ExportAllVehicleLocationsToExcel")';
 $('#export').click(function() {
  location.href = baseUrl + '/' + $('#LocationCode').val();
 });
</script>`

Comment: Check what errors you getting in the browser console. Clearly you script is not executing so I assume jquery is not loaded

Comment: There is no errors in the browser console. jquery is loaded as I have other functions inside the script tags which are working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139756/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-rmadd).